# SQL inserting a member example

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can you please show me an example of how to insert a new member with a first name, surname and a mobile number.

INSERT INTO Costumer
(FName, SName, MobileNumber )
VALUES
(Joshua,White,12345678);

Comment: Do you have the answer in the question ? Maybe I would add some quotes ...

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
INSERT INTO Costumer (FName, SName, MobileNumber) VALUES ("Joshua", "White", 12345678)
```

would work but you'd need to make sure MobileNumber is set to a number type. You'd need quotes, which I've added for you.

Comment: No problem :) Mark as answered if it's worked please :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it help ?

```
INSERT INTO Costumer (FName, SName, MobileNumber) VALUES ('Joshua','White','12345678');
```

Comment: David's works just like mine. Unless you're asking something else.